# MATLAB postpones disp calls when doing demanding calculations. Why is that?

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I am implementing an algorithm in MATLAB. Among other things it calculates the shortest paths etc. so it's quite demanding for my old computer. I've put in [disp()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/disp.html) calls through out the program to see what's happening all the time.

However when starting on a particulary heavy for loop the `disp()` seemes not to be called until the loop is over even though it comes before the loop. Why is that? I thought that MATLAB was really executing sequentially or am I just choking it with too many calculations and the `disp()` calls get the lowest priority?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am almost certain it is because of EDT.

That's the function [drawnow()](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/drawnow.html) is for. See [article of Yair Altman](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-and-the-event-dispatch-thread-edt/) for good explanation.

Summary: MATLAB graphics is Java Swing and operations happen on a special thread - Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Calling `drawnow();` flushes event queue and updates figure window.

Comment: Seems to exactly the case. Putting in drawnow(); after the disp makes the function output the disp and then do the for loop it seems. Nice!