# Stuck in while loop; MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, while-loop

I am fairly new to MatLab GUI building and I have a "continue" button in the GUI.

So basically, at some point in my program, the program has to wait for the user to click on the "continue" button to keep going.

The only way I can think of doing this is to make the program loop infinitely 
in a while loop until the button is clicked and it exits the loop. This does not seem to work.

So the loop is as follows:

```
while (get(handles.continue,'value')) == 0 
    disp('in the loop')
    guidata(hObject,handles);
end
```

However, it is not exiting the loop. I tried changing the button from a `pushbutton` to a `togglebutton` but it would not exit the loop.

I know it is not the most efficient way to make the program wait but can anyone tell me why it is not exiting that loop or suggest a more efficient way?

Comment: It seems you have same problem as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522447/breaking-from-for-loop-in-matlab-gui?rq=1). See accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this is to write a [callback](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/customizing-callbacks-in-guide.html) associated with the Continue button:

```
set(handles.continue, 'Callback', @continueProcessing);
```

Then, write the `continueProcessing` function to do whatever it is that you need to do after the user pushes the button. A prototype is below:

```
function continueProcessing(hObj, event)
    ...
end
```

`continueProcessing()` will run whenever the button is pushed. Note that callbacks in MATLAB *must* have the first two arguments be `hObj` (the handle of the component whose callback is now being called) and [`eventdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/writing-code-for-callbacks.html#f16-1001315).